# Guidance on how to write a Dockerfile for a static website [HTML,CSS,JS files]

Tags: html, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

i apologize in advance if anyone finds this to be noob question.I want to create a docker image of a static website
The location/folder dir is as follows:
HTML file: desktop/resume--CSS file: desktop/resume/css--Js file: desktop/resume/js--Jpeg file: desktop/resume/assets/img

```js
/*!
* Start Bootstrap - Resume v7.0.4 (https://startbootstrap.com/theme/resume)
* Copyright 2013-2021 Start Bootstrap
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-resume/blob/master/LICENSE)
*/
//
// Scripts
// 

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {

    // Activate Bootstrap scrollspy on the main nav element
    const sideNav = document.body.querySelector('#sideNav');
    if (sideNav) {
        new bootstrap.ScrollSpy(document.body, {
            target: '#sideNav',
            offset: 74,
        });
    };

    // Collapse responsive navbar when toggler is visible
    const navbarToggler = document.body.querySelector('.navbar-toggler');
    const responsiveNavItems = [].slice.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('#navbarResponsive .nav-link')
    );
    responsiveNavItems.map(function (responsiveNavItem) {
        responsiveNavItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (window.getComputedStyle(navbarToggler).display !== 'none') {
                navbarToggler.click();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Resume - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Google fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,400i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body id="page-top">
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top" id="sideNav">
            <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">
                <span class="d-block d-lg-none">Clarence Taylor</span>
                <span class="d-none d-lg-block"><img class="img-fluid img-profile rounded-circle mx-auto mb-2" src="assets/img/profile.jpg" alt="..." /></span>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#education">Education</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#interests">Interests</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#awards">Awards</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Page Content-->
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
            <!-- About-->
            <section class="resume-section" id="about">
                <div class="resume-section-content">
                    <h1 class="mb-0">
                        Clarence
                        <span class="text-primary">Taylor</span>
                    </h1>
                    <div class="subheading mb-5">
                        3542 Berry Street · Cheyenne Wells, CO 80810 · (317) 585-8468 ·
                        <a href="mailto:name@email.com">name@email.com</a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="lead mb-5">I am experienced in leveraging agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition.</p>
                    <div class="social-icons">
                        <a class="social-icon" href="#!"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                        <a class="social-icon" href="#!"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                        <a class="social-icon" href="#!"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="social-icon" href="#!"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr class="m-0" />
            <!-- Experience-->
            <section class="resume-section" id="experience">
                <div class="resume-section-content">
                    <h2 class="mb-5">Experience</h2>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between mb-5">
                        <div class="flex-grow-1">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">Senior Web Developer</h3>
                            <div class="subheading mb-3">Intelitec Solutions</div>
                            <p>Bring to the table win-win survival strategies to ensure proactive domination. At the end of the day, going forward, a new normal that has evolved from generation X is on the runway heading towards a streamlined cloud solution. User generated content in real-time will have multiple touchpoints for offshoring.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0"><span class="text-primary">March 2013 - Present</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between mb-5">
                        <div class="flex-grow-1">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">Web Developer</h3>
                            <div class="subheading mb-3">Intelitec Solutions</div>
                            <p>Capitalize on low hanging fruit to identify a ballpark value added activity to beta test. Override the digital divide with additional clickthroughs from DevOps. Nanotechnology immersion along the information highway will close the loop on focusing solely on the bottom line.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0"><span class="text-primary">December 2011 - March 2013</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between mb-5">
                        <div class="flex-grow-1">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">Junior Web Designer</h3>
                            <div class="subheading mb-3">Shout! Media Productions</div>
                            <p>Podcasting operational change management inside of workflows to establish a framework. Taking seamless key performance indicators offline to maximise the long tail. Keeping your eye on the ball while performing a deep dive on the start-up mentality to derive convergence on cross-platform integration.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0"><span class="text-primary">July 2010 - December 2011</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between">
                        <div class="flex-grow-1">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">Web Design Intern</h3>
                            <div class="subheading mb-3">Shout! Media Productions</div>
                            <p>Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0"><span class="text-primary">September 2008 - June 2010</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr class="m-0" />
            <!-- Education-->
            <section class="resume-section" id="education">
                <div class="resume-section-content">
                    <h2 class="mb-5">Education</h2>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between mb-5">
                        <div class="flex-grow-1">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">University of Colorado Boulder</h3>
                            <div class="subheading mb-3">Bachelor of Science</div>
                            <div>Computer Science - Web Development Track</div>
                            <p>GPA: 3.23</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0"><span class="text-primary">August 2006 - May 2010</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-between">
                        <div class="flex-grow-1">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">James Buchanan High School</h3>
                            <div class="subheading mb-3">Technology Magnet Program</div>
                            <p>GPA: 3.56</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex-shrink-0"><span class="text-primary">August 2002 - May 2006</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr class="m-0" />
            <!-- Skills-->
            <section class="resume-section" id="skills">
                <div class="resume-section-content">
                    <h2 class="mb-5">Skills</h2>
                    <div class="subheading mb-3">Programming Languages & Tools</div>
                    <ul class="list-inline dev-icons">
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-html5"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-js-square"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-angular"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-react"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-node-js"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-sass"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-less"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-wordpress"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-gulp"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-grunt"></i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fab fa-npm"></i></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="subheading mb-3">Workflow</div>
                    <ul class="fa-ul mb-0">
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                            Mobile-First, Responsive Design
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                            Cross Browser Testing & Debugging
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                            Cross Functional Teams
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                            Agile Development & Scrum
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr class="m-0" />
            <!-- Interests-->
            <section class="resume-section" id="interests">
                <div class="resume-section-content">
                    <h2 class="mb-5">Interests</h2>
                    <p>Apart from being a web developer, I enjoy most of my time being outdoors. In the winter, I am an avid skier and novice ice climber. During the warmer months here in Colorado, I enjoy mountain biking, free climbing, and kayaking.</p>
                    <p class="mb-0">When forced indoors, I follow a number of sci-fi and fantasy genre movies and television shows, I am an aspiring chef, and I spend a large amount of my free time exploring the latest technology advancements in the front-end web development world.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr class="m-0" />
            <!-- Awards-->
            <section class="resume-section" id="awards">
                <div class="resume-section-content">
                    <h2 class="mb-5">Awards & Certifications</h2>
                    <ul class="fa-ul mb-0">
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-trophy text-warning"></i></span>
                            Google Analytics Certified Developer
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-trophy text-warning"></i></span>
                            Mobile Web Specialist - Google Certification
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-trophy text-warning"></i></span>
                            1
                            <sup>st</sup>
                            Place - University of Colorado Boulder - Emerging Tech Competition 2009
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-trophy text-warning"></i></span>
                            1
                            <sup>st</sup>
                            Place - University of Colorado Boulder - Adobe Creative Jam 2008 (UI Design Category)
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-trophy text-warning"></i></span>
                            2
                            <sup>nd</sup>
                            Place - University of Colorado Boulder - Emerging Tech Competition 2008
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-trophy text-warning"></i></span>
                            1
                            <sup>st</sup>
                            Place - James Buchanan High School - Hackathon 2006
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-trophy text-warning"></i></span>
                            3
                            <sup>rd</sup>
                            Place - James Buchanan High School - Hackathon 2005
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Core theme JS-->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please can someone explain how to write a dockerfile for this? I have been trying but once the docker image is created it and i load it, it doesn't have CSS,JS formatting or the jpeg image, only the HTML file. Any detailed or step by step procedure to convert this to docker image would be really appreciated. Once again sorry for Noob question. Thank you
[image of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03sdj.png)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what type of web server you want to serve the files. If you want to use nginx, you can create a Dockerfile like this in desktop/resume

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Then build and run with

```
docker build -t mywebsite .
docker run -d -p 8080:80 mywebsite
```

Now you should be able to reach the website at http://localhost:8080/

Make sure that your start page is called index.html.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your detailed reply , I followed your steps and still am facing the same issue. The HTML part of the file [ the text] is loading but the formatting, page setup and images are not loading. I just want a simple website that displays a resume with the given CSS and JS file format with a picture of the person @HansKilian

Comment: I have added an image in the original question post , please have a look. Only text is being displayed no image or formatting.